# Recyclerview Item Removes and Reappears Immediately When Deleted android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to delete a list from recycler view.
Problem is when I delete the item,
It removes from the list but reappears immediately. (The method to delete works, so the item is deleted but it still remains in the list)

**Adapter**

```
 inner class AllSongsViewHolder(val binding: RcvLytAllSongsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
    binding.root
){
  init {
    binding.icDelete.setOnClickListener {
    onDeleteItemClickListener?.let { click -> click(song, bindingAdapterPosition)}
  }
 }
}

fun removeSongFromList(songList: List<Songs>, position: Int){
    this.songs = songList
    songList.toMutableList().removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, songList.size)
}
```

**Fragment**

```
..........
private var allSongs: List<Songs>? = null

//THIS IS THE VIEWMODEL FOR GETTING ALL ITEMS STORING IN ADAPTER
mainViewModel.mediaItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ result ->
        when(result.status){
        Status.SUCCESS -> {      
        result.data?.let { songs ->
        allSongsAdapter.songs = sortedBy as List<Songs>
        allSongs = song 
  }

allSongsAdapter.setOnDeleteItemClickListener { songx, position -> 
//delete
val contentResolver: ContentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver
songx.songUri?.let { it1 -> contentResolver.delete(it1, null, null) }
Toast.makeText(context, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//remove song from list
allSongsAdapter.removeSongFromList(allSongsAdapter.songs, position)
```

I tried to do It from the adapter itself, didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

well, item isn't removed in "original" array in fact

```
songList.toMutableList().removeAt(position)
```

`toMutableList()` is returning new mutable array, in which you are removing item at `position`, but never assign this mutable modified array to value, "original" `songList` still have this item. consider this snippet for `removeSongFromList` body:

```
val newList = songList.toMutableList()
newList.removeAt(position)
this.songs = newList
notifyItemRemoved(position)
```

also `notifyItemRangeChanged` isn't needed here, nothing changes, only one item removed

Comment: This works when I stay in thesame fragment, but when I leave the fragment and come back to the same fragment (e.g via press of back button), the deleted item reappears.

Comment: so my solution works for your issue. now you've found another problem related to not storing current `this.songs` list, its content is always restored. code responsible for removing item works only for view and modified (mutable) list, won't remove item from database or api, from which you are loading initial list. and you didn't posted how do you retrieve this list

Comment: probably you should put inside `removeSongFromList` method some more code for removing data also in source of list (api/database). closing `Fragment` and opening new instance of it will load initial list without removed items at start (as they won't exist anywhere in that moment)

Comment: Actually, its a music app. -> Source is gotten from all music from user phone,

So in my fragment (Where I implemented the delete method in adapter), I have a viewModel that observe gets all Songs and observe changes to the List of songs. Please see my updated question

Comment: Check my question, I added a comment in the fragment -> "//THIS IS THE VIEWMODEL FOR GETTING ALL ITEMS STORING IN ADAPTER". 

and this is how I am now deleting
allSongsAdapter.removeSongFromList(allSongsAdapter.songs, position)

Comment: One would think the viewModel will automatically observe changes, cause the item(song) is infact been deleted from the phone.

Comment: why do you think that item (song) is deleted from device? you didn't posted code for that, `removeSongFromList` isn't removing file, only removes item from list

Comment: I am deleting the song from fragment...The code is there
...
songx.songUri?.let { it1 -> contentResolver.delete(it1, null, null) }

The song cannot be played when I navigate back to the frament (After reappearing in the list)

Comment: oh, I see, don't know the cause... seems like some problem in loading "historical" data, probably in `mainViewModel`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232501/discussion-between-ibramazin-and-snachmsm).